# I can't find syntax for adding var into style backgroundImage,

Tags: javascript

here is the code:

```
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

  var myElement = document.getElementById('testest');
  myElement.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/covers/cover-1.png')";
```

I want to add var randomNumber to replace "1" in url backgroundImage property.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: `"url('img/covers/cover-" + randomNumber + ".png')"` or `\`url('img/covers/cover-${randomNumber}.png')\``

Comment: basic string concatenation?

Comment: Thanks @Taki that worked!

Answer (score 1):

Create the variable url outside and add it to the backgroundImage attribute

```
var img = 'img/covers/cover-'+<dynamicdata>+'.png';
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + img + ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to interpolate with backticks.

```
myElement.style.backgroundImage = `url(img/covers/cover-${randomNumber}.png)`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is mentioned in the code snippet

```js
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
var url = `url('img/covers/cover-${randomNumber}.png')`;
console.log(url);
```

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
var url = `url('img/covers/cover-${randomNumber}.png')`;
var myElement = document.getElementById('testest');
myElement.style.backgroundImage = url
```